# Seamless Looping with SoundPool on Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I am trying to loop short (20kb), gapless ogg files with the SoundPool class and cannot get consistent results while testing on hardware. It always plays back perfectly using the emulator but when I test on a Nexus 1, or on a Samsumg Galaxy Tab 10.1 there are audible pops or clicks at every loop point. What is very strange is that while consistent once the application has started, the clicks are slightly different every time I restart the app and on rare occasions (more frequently on the tablet) the loop plays correctly.

The results are no better using MediaPlayer. Is it unreasonable to expect gapless playback of audio loops on android? Surely someone has similar functionality working properly? If so I would love to see an example of how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm in the same boat, WAV files perform badly the same: a perfect gapless loop seems impossible. If you try to fadein/out the first and last 10 samples of the track, then you'll hear very distinctly the millisecond long pause, no clicks, but the fade is very audible.. o_O

Comment: Tough it's a lot of trouble for what you want, you could always use AudioTrack, which uses a continuous stream of bits.

Comment: It will sound stupid but it is (apparently) unreasonable to expect gapless, seamless audio playback.

Answer (score 4):

I used a hack that works fine for single files:

```
HACK_loopTimer = new Timer();
HACK_loopTask = new TimerTask() {               
    @Override public void run() {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
    }
};
long waitingTime = mMediaPlayer.getDuration()-mHackLoopingPreview;
HACK_loopTimer.schedule(HACK_loopTask, waitingTime, waitingTime);
```

Just set `mHackLoopingPreview` to a reasonable amount; I'm using 100ms and it is working fine. I have to agree that this is a less than ideal and *ugly* solution, but at least it does its job.

Comment: it works, but not when application is in background there is a little gap in looping

Comment: Could you extend the example a bit more? For e.g., where do you call start() or prepare()?

Comment: This didn't work for me at all. Maybe because I didn't implement it in the right place like @Primož'c0dehunter'Kralj implied.

Answer (score 1):

I found other solution:

```
afd = assetManager.openFd(nameSound);

player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                     afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength() - 1000);
afd.close();
player.prepare();
player.setLooping(true);
player.start();
```

You only need to define the duration 1000(1ms) less instead that the total duration. Y eso es todo, problema resuelto!!!!

Comment: not working, a pause beetwen loops happens

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a cop out but there are a 2 things you can try, the first of which worked for me.

1. Make you audio files ogg format at 48kHz sample rate and 48Kbit/s (This worked for me)
2. You can create 2 MediaPlayer Objects and (just like the @Beowulf Bjornson 's answer) approximately <= 100ms start MediaPlayer #2 just before MediaPlayer #1 ends and alternate between the entire time.

Hope people that come here tries what I've said because I've wasted about 3 days trying to figure this out only to be amazed that there isn't an out of the box way to do this flawlessly.