# Play breakfree sound soundpool

Tags: java, android, runnable, soundpool

I am trying to play a sound when my wheel is scratched(DJ Turn Table) the sound file is playing like a timer `tick tick tick`. 
It is a pretty small file *00:02*. 
I want this file to play almost in a continuous way like a real scratch. 
I am using `soundpool` here and I also tried to increase the rate to 2f but still the same. 
Here is a runnable I am calling when wheel is rotated:

```
r1 = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        streamId = s.play(R.raw.clickslow, maxVolume, maxVolume, 100, 0, 2f);       
    }
};
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631717/seamless-looping-with-soundpool-on-android) might be helpful.

Comment: not working for me may be I need a smaller sound file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using a very small sound file and running the same over the UI thread and it is working very close to what I needed now thanks alot for help.